# Error using sp_trace_create with parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, trace

I'm running the following SQL on SQL Server 2000:

```
exec sp_trace_create @options = 2,
         @tracefile = N'h:\\trace.trc',
         @filecount = 2
```

and am getting the following error and can't understand why:

> Procedure expects parameter '@tracefile' of type 'nvarchar(128)'

If I pass all of the parameters in like so:

declare @id int

```
exec sp_trace_create @id output,
         @options = 2,
         @tracefile = N'h:\\trace.trc',
         @filecount = 2,
         @maxfilesize = 5,
         @stoptime = '2013-8-15'
```

I get the error:

> Procedure or function sp_trace_create has too many arguments specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin Smith has answered https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24728/8783

This will work :

```
DECLARE @new_trace_id INT;

EXECUTE master.dbo.sp_trace_create
  @someinteger = @new_trace_id OUTPUT,
  @someinteger = 0,
  @someinteger = N'C:\trace\TestTrace.trc';


  -- get trace status 
  SELECT * FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(NULL)
  -- stop trace
  EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @traceid = 1 -- CHANGE THIS AS PER YOUR TRACE id
                    , @status = 0  
  go 
  -- delete trace
  EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @traceid = 1  -- CHANGE THIS AS PER YOUR TRACE id
                    , @status = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why but it appears that `sp_trace_create` requires all parameters be passed.  This includes the `@traceid` parameter.  The error is definitely misleading.  Add the `@traceid` parameter and the next error you get will be for @maxfilesize.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that and updated my question accordingly

Comment: `SQL 2000` doesn't have an `@filecount` parameter.  That's not until `SQL 2005`

Comment: @rhughes This is the link to what Kenneth mentioned http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2007/06/29/did-you-know-a-6th-parameter-when-creating-a-trace.aspx

Comment: Only the first three parameters are mandatory. [There are six in total](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190362.aspx) but as it only accepts positional parameters all preceding ones must be supplied.

Comment: The OP is using [SQL 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260328(v=sql.80).aspx).  The 6th parameter was not added until SQL 2005.